# Few Errors Using Swift

Tags: swift

I was trying to build a small random number guessing game using the command line tool in Xcode.

I have also added an image of the errors that come from the Xcode ide

```
import Foundation

var randomNumber = 1
var userGuess = 1
var continueGuessing = true
var keepPlaying = true
var input = ""

while (keepPlaying) {
    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101)) //to get a random number between 0-100
    println(" The random number to guess is: \(randomNumber)"  );
    while (continueGuessing) {
        println(" Pick a number between 0 and 100. ")
        input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().
            availableData,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! //get keyboard input
        input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options:NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)//strip off the/n
        userGuess = input.toInt()!
        if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
            continueGuessing = false
            println("correct number!");

        }
//nested if statement
        else if (userGuess > randomNumber){
            //user guessed to high
            println("your guess is too high");
        }

    else {
        //no reason to check if userGuess < random. it has to be.
        println("Play again? Y or N");
        input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData,
            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding!
            input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: <#NSStringCompareOptions#>.LiteralSearch, range: nil);
            }  if (input == "N" || input == "n"){
            keepPlaying = false
        }
        continueGuessing = true
```

[image: Here is an image of the code from Xcode ide]

Comment: Instead of posting screenshot, please paste the error in text here. And there are a lot of typos in your codes obviously. Follow the error hint & correct them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two small mistakes:

You have a newline here and also need to cast to a String - change this:

```
input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().
        availableData,encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

to this:

```
input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
```

You also left the XCode autogenerated placeholder for NSStringCompareOptions - change this:

```
input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: <#NSStringCompareOptions#>.LiteralSearch, range: nil);
```

to this:

```
input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Here is your full snippet with the corrections above:

```
while (keepPlaying) {
randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101)) //to get a random number between 0-100
println(" The random number to guess is: \(randomNumber)"  );
while (continueGuessing) {
    println(" Pick a number between 0 and 100. ")
    input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options:NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)//strip off the/n
    userGuess = input.toInt()!
    if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
        continueGuessing = false
        println("correct number!");

    }
        //nested if statement
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber){
        //user guessed to high
        println("your guess is too high");
    }

    else {
        //no reason to check if userGuess < random. it has to be.
        println("Play again? Y or N");
        input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
            input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil);
    }  if (input == "N" || input == "n"){
        keepPlaying = false
    }
    continueGuessing = true
```